# JDT: Nesting MethodInvocation

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am trying to use Eclipse JDT's AST model to create a command like the following:

```
tmpStringBuffer.append("Content: ").append(gateId);
```

What works: to create

```
tmpStringBuffer.append("Content: ");
```

with the below code

```
MethodInvocation mi = ast.newMethodInvocation();
mi.setExpression(ast.newSimpleName("tmpStringBuffer"));
mi.setName(ast.newSimpleName("append"));
sl = ast.newStringLiteral();
sl.setLiteralValue("Content: " );
mi.arguments().add(sl);
bufferBlock.statements().add(ast.newExpressionStatement(mi));
```

But how to set the second `.append(gateId)` (to get the command shown above). It is not a second added `MethodInvocation` command as it will result in  `tmpStringBuffer.append("Content: ", append(gateId));`. But the result should be `tmpStringBuffer.append("Content: ").append(gateId);`.

*AstView* tells me it is somehow nested. How can it be appended?

Answer (score 1):

The second `MethodInvocation` should be nested as an expression of the first `MethodInovcation`. Try the code below:

```
MethodInvocation nestedMI = ast.newMethodInvocation();
nestedMI.setExpression(ast.newSimpleName("tmpStringBuffer"));
nestedMI.setName(ast.newSimpleName("append"));
sl = ast.newStringLiteral();
sl.setLiteralValue("Content: " );
nestedMI.arguments().add(s1);

MethodInvocation mi = ast.newMethodInvocation();
mi.setExpression(nestedMI);
mi.setName(ast.newSimpleName("append"));
mi.arguments().add(ast.newSimpleName("gateId"));

bufferBlock.statements().add(ast.newExpressionStatement(mi));
```

Comment: @HolmDressler Please consider accepting the answer since it works for you.